# Displaying output of php within jquery colorbox ... getting undefined index error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, colorbox

I hope someone can help me, I have created a simple html form with drop down menu's, the drop down menus are populated from a mysql data base, the user must select from two drop downs and this will then display the data ( both selections make the sql query)
This all works correctly within the HTML however I am trying to jazz it up a bit and have the output display within a jquery colorbox (popup).

I am not sure how to format the syntax for the jquery function .. this is what I have so far

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
        $("input#formsubmit").colorbox({href: function(){
    var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');
    return url;
}, innerWidth:920, innerHeight:"86%", iframe:true});                
            });
    </script>
```

This correctly launches the colorbox pop up and fires the php "action" from my form but the $_POST attributes are not sent across and I just get an unidentified index error from mysql.

Can some one please help me ?

Im sure its something simple, but I cant figure it out.

Many thanks

Adding PHP ...

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("verify") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Entitlement FROM products WHERE ProductName = '$_POST[product]' AND CustomerType = '$_POST[customer]'")
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['Entitlement'] ;
echo "<br />";
}


?>
```

Comment: unidentified index error is in php. show your php code !

Comment: PHP above, all this works fine in plain HTML , only fails when using the colorbox/jquery to display the result. I think its failing because the jquery is not sending the $_POST attributes to the php

Comment: @Gary : Post please exactly the error you get so we can detect precisely where the error and in which index it is :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <?php

  // Checking for valid post data
  if (isset($_POST['product']) && isset($_POST['customer']) && !empty($_POST['product']) && !empty($_POST['customer'])) {

    // Cleaning post data
    $proudct = mysql_escape_string($_POST['product']);
    $customer = mysql_escape_string($_POST['customer']);

    // db connnection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("verify") or die(mysql_error());

    // Quering
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Entitlement FROM products WHERE ProductName = '$proudct' AND CustomerType = '$customer'") or die(mysql_error());

    // Printing result
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['Entitlement'];
      echo "<br />";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: The php works fine , the correct variables are passed and I get the correct output, I am now trying to display the output in the jquery colorbox .... I only get the unidentified index error when calling the php from within the jquery function

Comment: @DBK : your above code test the same variable which is $_POST['product'] if it is empty for 2 times so i guess that you want the second test to test the customer variable and not the product one try to solve that may be index error diseappear

Comment: Tried the above and now the unidentifed index error is gone but the colorbox is empty , works fine when not using jquery (as before)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell how may this code works with you :)

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT Entitlement FROM products WHERE ProductName = '$_POST[product]' AND CustomerType = '$_POST[customer]'");?>
```

You have 2 error the first one the single quote beside the index in your post variable and must be like this `$_POST['product']`,`$_POST['customer']` then the second error is that you must encapsulate your variable inside the string as following `{$_POST['product']}`,`{$_POST['customer']}`

Try these work around then tell me the result :)